# how to remove white space from product name during custom product collection?

Tags: magento2.2, catalog, product-collection, category-products, product-sorting

I am getting stuck with white space in set order during product collection in magento 2.

I want to get product details with ascending order via name but name has white space. I have removed white space from admin but it is not removing.

So is it possible to remove white space during getting product collection in ascending order via name?

I am using below code:

```
$categoryId = 54; // YOUR CATEGORY ID
$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);

$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setOrder('name','ASC');;

foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) 
{

$proname = $product->getName();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($proname);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Untested code:

```
$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
            'trim_name',
            'TRIM({{name}})'
            ['name' => 'name']
        );
$categoryProducts->getSelect()>order('trim_name ASC');
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is the working code:

```
$categoryId = 54;
$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('name','ASC');

foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) 
{
    $proname = $product->getName();
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($proname);
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between my code and your code? By mistake,  I have typed ; in the code when posting this question.

Comment: I have added addAttributeToSort which should work.